# -log of a column data

Tags: awk, logarithm

I have a data file which looks like the following:

```
-1.98614
-1.99195
-2.28257
-2.09129
-2.08449
-2.0765
-2.0379
-2.25625
-2.04351
-2.09871
-2.17877 ...
```

I want to take the `-log(base 10)` of each line (awk command) and have it in a new file. Would you please help me with that?

Comment: Ouch, log of negative numbers ... don't you want to compute `log10(-x)`?

Comment: -log or say antilog of a column of numbers? -log(-1.986) or log 1/-1.986 which is 0.010471285.

Comment: Please reformulate your post by writing you want to compute the antilog and NOT the log_10 function of numbers, it is completely different!

Answer (score 5):

The antilog base 10 of a number `x` is another way to express `10^x`. Since `awk` does not have a built-in `pow(x,y)` to raise the power `y` of `x`, you need to rewrite it with the help of `exp` and `log`:

```
awk '{print exp($1*log(10));}' file
```

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the decimal logarithm by dividing with the natural logarithm of 10.

```
awk '{print log(-$1)/log(10)}' file
```

will give you what you want.

Comment: I receive the following error?                                                                  awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=DihedBPBPradian FNR=249949) warning: log: received negative argument -3.11768

Comment: @amir: Did you use the version with `-log($1)` or the version with `log(-$1)`.  The logarithm of a negative number is a complex number; only strictly positive numbers have a real logarithm.  Or does your data have both positive and negative values?  If it has both, you need to decide how to handle the negative numbers correctly.

Comment: @amir Are the numbers in your file positive or negative? If they are positive take the `log($1)`, if they are negative take `log(-$1)`. You can't calculate the logarithm of a negative number, unless you use complex arithmetic, which AFAIK awk does not support.

Comment: I have both positive and negative numbers in my file.so how can I separate them from each other and then take -log of positive numbers?

Comment: @amir That really depends on what you are trying to achieve. If your algorithm should accept negative numbers then you can't just take the logarithm, unless you accept that the output will not always be real.

Comment: Ok. I found an awk command to separate positive numbers.  awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i>=0) print $i} ' file. thanks for your help.